# how to disappear keyboard onCreate Method?

Tags: android, android-activity

friends,

i have a EditText on simple activity with a button.
when  every i move from one activity to this acivity focus is automatically set to EditText and keyboard appears in phone.

i dont want to open keyboard untill i click on editText.

can any one guide me what should i do?

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following line of code to make sure the keyboard doesn't pop up when the activity starts and only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText

Place it in the onCreate method of your activity

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Awesome! This was the only solution that worked for me when the activity has the following flag: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustNothing"`

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: i have used it
EditText TextBox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
       TextBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); 
but when i click on edit text next time kayboard does not appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the same thing in AndroidMenifest file for that particular activity like:

```
        <activity
            android:name="Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
```

This will also work for you :)